# White lines in OSM (OpenLayers)

Tags: html, openlayers, openstreetmap

I have this piece of code in a JSP to show a map using OSM (OpenStreetMap, a collaborative project to create a free editable map of the world) but I see some white lines in the map

```
<div class="windowContentMap" >
    <div id="Map" style="width: 97%; height: 94%"></div>
                        <script src="http://www.openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
                        <script>
                            var lat            = '${lat}';
                            var lon            = '${lng}';
                            var zoom           =  9;

                            var fromProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");   // Transform from WGS 1984
                            var toProjection   = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"); // to Spherical Mercator Projection
                            var position       = new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat).transform( fromProjection, toProjection);

                            map = new OpenLayers.Map("Map");
                            var mapnik         = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
                            map.addLayer(mapnik);

                            var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers" );
                            map.addLayer(markers);
                            markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(position));
                            map.setCenter(position, zoom);

                            var myLocation = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(lon, lat).transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');

                        </script>

                    </div>
</div>


.windowContentMap div{
    height: 334px;
    display: block;
    border-left: 1px solid #efefef;
    border-right: 1px solid #efefef;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your problem is with CSS, not with JS/OpenLayers.

Try with this

```
#Map {
    height: 334px;
    display: block;
    border-left: 1px solid #efefef;
    border-right: 1px solid #efefef;
}
```

You are giving border to all the divs children of div.windowContentMap , so also the divs created by OpenLayers are getting the border.

Comment: I have the same problem but I don't use OpenLayers or CSS style for div. I use Leaflet to display OpenStreetMap. Any idea why?